Disable XAML binding warning? #pragma warning disable XC0022
I am working w/ Maui XAML, but I would like to disable this XAML warning on a single file (ok maybe a few ;)).
XamlC XC0022 warning : Binding could be compiled if x:DataType is specified.
In C# I would
#pragma warning disable XC0022


Have a look here https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/20568 there was a bug

Honestly you should address this warning it will actually give you a great performance boost

@FreakyAli Thanks of course I would, it's not possible in ALL cases.

You could assign null if there is nothing

x:DataType="{x:Null}" just moves the warning... I was trying that from @MustafaMutasim comment.
XamlC XC0023 warning : Binding could be compiled if x:DataType is not explicitly null.

Just add it in nowarn in that case i guess

Thanks but the question states "I would like to disable this XAML warning on a single file"

This could be related to XamlC XC0022 warning : Binding could be compiled if x:DataType is specified after upgrade to 8.0.7, I see others report that after upgrading to 8.0.10 the problem disappeared, see https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/21288#issuecomment-2008125053

@AlexandarMay-MSFT I assume you mean Microsoft.Maui.Controls we are at 8.0.14 but I'll see there's 8.0.40 to try.

@kenny Yes, that was what I meant. Please follow up that thread:https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/21288 if it still doesn't work.

sorry @AlexandarMay-MSFT I meant to answer 8.0.40 squashed the warning. Make that the answer and I'll accept it.

To squish the XamlC XC0022 warning :Binding could be compiled if x:DataType is specified., you can use the latest Microsoft.Maui.Controls:8.0.40.
Related issue link: XamlC XC0022 warning

this worked around the problem and I accepted it as the answer, but I would think XAML pragmas could be a useful tool in some TBD situation.

@kenny Yes, I agree, use #pragma would be more handy way to handle the scenario.
